# Ergodic transformations, their Poisson suspensions and their Krieger types

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $T$ be an ergodic nonsingular tranformation of a Lebesgue space. Suppose that the Poisson transformation $T^*$ of $T$ is well-defined and ergodic. Denote by $\alpha$ the Krieger type of $T$ and by $\beta$ the Krieger type of $T^*$. List all possible values for pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$.

---

This problem was posed 12 March of 2022 by Alexandre Danilenko (Kharkiv, Ukraine) on [page 115](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=115) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize:** Two bottles of vodka.